# Create a script that will log you into Chrome

Tags: javascript, python, macros

Can someone help me create a script that will open Google Chrome, select the three dots on the upper right hand portion of the screen, select the "Sign-Into Chrome" button, enter my credentials, hit enter.

It's fairly simple, yet I don't have a clue how to achieve this. I would post my attempts at doing this but it is useless. I simply want to click a button, and it will launch Chrome and log me in so that I don't have to. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't Chrome have a "stay logged in" option?

Comment: Take a look at the selenium library. There is example that show how to open browser and login with putting credentials and clicking login button

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this as a practicality, then it's probably easiest to just google search for some chrome extension. If you're doing this for the experience, the google search how to write chrome extensions.
I'm not trying to be a jerk, I don't know how to do what you asked, just trying to guide you to what you're looking for